# What is the time zone in finland for php?

Tags: php, laravel, timezone

I have used the php's default timezone 'Europe/Moscow' for the finland.
But it is running 3 hours behind.
I have use the Laravel 5.6 and set the timezone in `app.php` in configuration.

`'timezone' => env("APP_TIMEZONE",'Europe/Moscow')`

So when i insert something on `2019-09-14 20:12:00` it shows me `2019-09-14 17:12:00` in the database.

Comment: It is  GMT+3 / EEST

Comment: Okay @PrafullaKumarSahu then what should i write in the timezone as mention above?

Comment: For Finland you should use `Europe/Helsinki`.

Comment: Okay let me try with this.

Answer (score 0):

here is list of supported [timezone](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) for europe find your nearby [timezone](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.europe.php)

try to add `Europe/Helsinki` its timezone is utc +3:00

hope this helps you

Comment: I have go through it already. Still didn't get the answer that's why i have posted here.

Comment: Okay i try with this and let you know

Answer (score 0):

After changing **app.php**, make sure you run:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

This is needed to clear the cache of config settings. If you notice that your timestamps are still wrong after changing the timezone in your app.php file, then running the above command should refresh everything, and your new timezone should be effective.

Answer (score 0):

go to the file `config/app.php` and change this entry:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Timezone
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the default timezone for your application, which
| will be used by the PHP date and date-time functions. We have gone
| ahead and set this to a sensible default for you out of the box.
|
*/

'timezone' => 'Europe/Moscow',
```

See full list [PHP Supported Timezones](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_timezones.asp#europe)

After changes *`app.php`* you should run this command `php artisan config:cache`